# how to install sub modules of keras and tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Why I am not able to import following modules--

```python
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

I am using

## python(3.6)
TensorFlow(1.15)
keras(2.1)
spyder4 IDE

The error I am facing

> `No module named 'tensorflow.keras'`

I have tried this

```python
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core import 
Reshape,Dense,Dropout,Activation,Flatten
```

I already uninstall and reinstall Keras but it is not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the version of TensorFlow and Keras.

Practically, you want to import Keras from TensorFlow, which is the right approach (you do not even need to install Keras separately).

However, you are using TensorFlow 1.5 version, which **does not have Keras** implemented inside it.

You have to use a newer version of TensorFlow to solve your problem, at least 1.8.

However, I would recommend that you install TensorFlow 2.2.0 alone, remember that you do not need to install Keras separately.

Comment: i am using python 3.6 well tensorflow is compatible for it?

Comment: Normally it should work, but you could update to Python 3.7 just to be sure. Python 3.8 works only with TensorFlow >=2.2.0 version

Comment: @Ashutosh did my answer solve you problem? If so, please mark the answer as accepted. Thank you.